# How to access models inside Backbone Marionete App?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

actually i'm a backend developer so be gentle if my question is so dumb :)

I have an Backbone app initialized like this:

```
var AgendaApp = Mn.Application.extend({
    onStart: function() {
        ...
        ...

        var bookings = new Bookings();
        bookings.startStream({
            remove: false
        });
    }
    var agendaApp = ...
```

As you see bookings istance is staying inside onStart function scope. There is no chance to access them using debug console. For example i want to run something like this:

```
agendaApp.bookings.fetch()
```

What frontend developers doing at these stiuations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the model a property of the app, e.g. `this.bookings = new Bookings()`. Then you can access it anywhere you have the app, e.g. `agendaApp.bookings.fetch()`.